# PolymerJS: How to properly use paper-material

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I'd like to use the shadow animation of paper-material on a card and when I use something like this, it works:

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="todoapp">
    <style>
    </style>

    <section on-click="tapAction">
        <paper-material elevation="0" animated>  
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus molestiae quibusdam officiis libero quia ad, unde, assumenda totam soluta modi ullam cumque rem porro tempore ratione doloribus ab delectus optio. Excepturi voluptates mollitia, soluta at, obcaecati magni doloremque aperiam quisquam, esse ipsa voluptas commodi, quis.
        </paper-material>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    todoapp.tapAction = function (e) {
        var target = e.target;

        if (!target.down) {
            target.elevation += 1;

            if (target.elevation === 1) {
                target.down = true;
            }
        } else {
            target.elevation -= 1;
            if (target.elevation === 0) {
                target.down = false;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

But as soon as my `paper-material` element has another element in it, it refuses to work:

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="todoapp">
    <style>
    </style>

    <section on-click="tapAction">
        <paper-material elevation="0" animated>  
            <h1>Doesn't work</h1>
        </paper-material>
    </section>
</template>
```

The only difference is that I used an `h1` element in the 2nd example. Then the animation just does not work.

I tried adding a plunker, but for some reason I haven't managed to make it work, because It must confuse some of the necessary imports. Can someone recommend a code editor, that fits for polymer?

And would it be possible to put all my code inside of the `paper-material` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case the target is the `paper-material` element and in the second case, target is `h1`. You might want to assign id to the paper material element and operate on that.

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="todoapp">
    <style>
    </style>

    <section on-click="tapAction">
        <paper-material elevation="0" animated id="material">  
            <h1>Doesn't work</h1>
        </paper-material>
    </section>
</template>
```

And in the script

```
<script>
    todoapp.tapAction = function (e) {
        var target = todoapp.$.material;

        if (!target.down) {
            target.elevation += 1;

            if (target.elevation === 1) {
                target.down = true;
            }
        } else {
            target.elevation -= 1;
            if (target.elevation === 0) {
                target.down = false;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hma9wJrlW4lNrW7Qwi4n?p=preview